# Convert CSV string to Array keys and a value of 1 or true

Tags: php, arrays

Please could someone help find a better solution to the code below.

Here is my existing solution:

```
$list = '54,78,3,5';

$list = explode(",",$list);

foreach($list as $k => $v) { $compare[$v] = 1; }
```

when i run array_flip instead of the foreach on $list it returns an array like this:

```
Array(
    54 => 0,
    78 => 1,
    ...
)
```

I need this so another array which is already in this format can be compared with an IF statment:

```
Array(
    54 => 1,
    78 => 1,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$list = '54,78,3,5';
$list = explode(",",$list);
$array = array_combine($list, array_fill(0, count($list), 1));
print_r($array);

Array
(
    [54] => 1
    [78] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

[`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) will create an array with all of its values being the number `1` at the same size as the `$list` array. [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) then creates a new array with the values of `$list` as the keys and the values created by `array_fill()`;

[Demo](https://eval.in/210517)

Comment: Works great and much faster on my dataset! will accept after the time limit expires. Thanks John

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the original `$list` to be a variable? Can't you just make it an array from the start wherever the data comes from, and append 1 or true to the value?

Otherwise, before your current `foreach`, add a new loop and go through `$list` (which you made into an array) and make a new array appending the required value to each key (keys taken from `$list`):

```
foreach ($list as $key)
  {
    $new_array[$key] = 1;
  }
```